# offset left of image in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a carousel with a list of images. I use the following code to see how many images are on the screen at a time. There can be 10 images but only 5 on the screen. You have to click on the next button to see the remaining 5 images. For some reason, the code below doesn't work well (Even if there are images outside the screen, it returns the incorrect number of images fully shown on the screen, happens when the container is not at 100% of the browser width). Can someone please help?

```
this.$samples.each(function (i, cardEl) {
    var x = $(cardEl).offset().left + $(cardEl).width() - this.$exampleGrid.offset().left;
    if (x <= winWidth) {
        shownCount += 1;
    }
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work well"

Comment: Ditto on what JDB said. The math here seems to suggest you're 1. checking for the right edge of the "card", 2. If the card is within the window, increment the total visible cards. Is that it? What's the expected result versus the actual result?

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, but I don't get the right numbers. Thanks